# React Native Socket.io not working in background

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, socket.io, android-background

In my app the user via a button can start a special mode where various GPS, BLE etc services are activated. Among these, I need the server to know in real time which users have this mode enabled. I figured the only way is to establish a socket.io connection. However on Android after a couple of minutes the connection is interrupted. Tried following what recommended an [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63432839/how-to-prevent-socket-io-from-disconnecting-when-react-native-app-is-in-backgrou) but still nothing.

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import {AppState} from 'react-native'

export default () => {
  const appState = useRef(AppState.currentState);
  var interval

  const _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
      if (
        appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) &&
        nextAppState === "active"
      ) {
        console.log("App has come to the foreground!");
        //clearInterval when your app has come back to the foreground
        BackgroundTimer.clearInterval(interval)
        
      }else{
        //app goes to background
        console.log('app goes to background')
        //tell the server that your app is still online when your app detect that it goes to background
        interval = BackgroundTimer.setInterval(()=>{
          console.log('connection status ', socket.connected)
          socket.emit('online')
        },5000)
      appState.current = nextAppState;
      console.log("AppState", appState.current);
  }

useEffect (() => {
    AppState.addEventListener("change", _handleAppStateChange);

    return () => {
      AppState.removeEventListener("change", _handleAppStateChange);
    };
},[])



}
```

The error I receive is "transport error".
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to use polling only for the transports when opening socket for the background mode?

Comment: No, I hadn't thought of that, but it might be a good idea. How can I change the transport type at runtime?

Comment: The best would be open another connection when going to background mode.

Comment: I tried to create a new socket.io connection with only pooling as transport method  when the app goes in background but still it doesn't solve the problem. What is strange is that the problem is exclusively socket.io. In fact the background task keeps running and in an attempt to recover the connection when it is lost API calls are successfully made to the server to ask for new access tokens in background. So I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: In the link you provided, there's second answer which to use ForeGroundService?
Have you tried it before?

Answer (score 0):

Activities in the background are killed for resources on Android after very brief amounts of time.  You need to use a foreground Service (which can still be killed, but is less likely to be)but even that won't work forever.  Android is not meant to have reliable background execution for power saving purposes.  Even if you did use a foreground service your app will be under Doze mode restrictions once the screen is off (allowed only a brief window to do computation every 15 minutes, except for high priority push notifications.  And those are limited as well to only so many per hour).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually in my app there is already a foreground service which makes the BLE service work in the background. However the problem is that I have implemented this natively in java while the socket connection (and the auth logic) is in the javascript side. so I really don't know how to do it. On IOS the socket connection is not interrupted, however it is probably due to the use of the gps in background which prevent the app from being closed by the system.

Comment: You'd need the socket to be managed natively as well.  It needs to be owned by the foreground service, not the Activity.  To be honest-  React Native was not a good choice for this kind of app.  Or at the very least, it should have been React Native for the UI only, with all logic done in native.  cross platform frameworks like RN work poorly when the behavior on different platforms are hard to abstract.

Comment: You are absolutely right, but right now the biggest problem that prevents me from moving the socket connection to the native side is the handling of authentication, like the request for new auth tokens for the socket when they expire, which is all js side. As I said in the other comment, what is strange is that the problem seems to be exclusively with socket.io. In fact the background task keeps running and in an attempt to recover the connection when it is lost API calls are successfully made to the server to ask for new access tokens in background. So I don't understand what's going on